# How to get geolocated Tweets near location using twitter4j

Tags: java, android, twitter

This is my first question here. I need to get tweets from any user near a location, and then put these tweets in a map as markers.
I have written this code to do the search:

```
private AsyncTwitter twitter;
twitter = new TwitterHelper(this).getAsyncTwitter();   //Twitter helper is a helper class to connect to Twitter using Twitter4J library
twitter.addListener(new TwitterListener() {

        @Override
        public void searched(QueryResult queryResult) {

            List<Status> qrTweets = queryResult.getTweets();

            for (Status tweet : qrTweets ) {
                Log.v("Results",tweet.getId() + " " + "@" + tweet.getUser().getScreenName()  + " : " + tweet.getText() + " :::" + tweet.getCreatedAt() + " :::" + tweet.getUser().getLocation());
                GeoLocation geoLocation = tweet.getGeoLocation();
                if (geoLocation != null) {
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(geoLocation.getLatitude(), geoLocation.getLongitude());
                    Log.v(TAG, "Tweet:" + latLng.toString());
                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(tweet.getText()));
                } else {
                    Log.v(TAG, "No location");
                }

            }
        }
}
twitter.search(new Query().geoCode(new GeoLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude),10,Query.KILOMETERS.toString()));
```

I get a lot of tweets but none of them have `GeoLocation` data and I can't add to the map.

I have been searching this forum and reading `twitter4j` docs and I've found something about `QueryFilters` but I don't know if I can apply to this problem because in this case there is no `TwitterStream` to filter.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.